# how to clear DataTableSource for PaginatedDataTable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am trying to update record in PaginatedDataTable in flutter, but let's say I have 5 records, and I update the record now, it will show 10 old record, 5 the old, and the no change data.

What is the best way to clear the DataTableSource (clear DataCell) for PaginatedDataTable to update them with new one?
this is declaration for the MySource:

```
 MySource mySource = new MySource(id, sub, c_date, m_date, status);
```

this is class for DataTableSource:

```
class MySource extends DataTableSource {
  List<String> value1;
  List<String> value2;
  List<String> value3;
  List<String> value4;
  List<String> value5;
  String a;
  String b;
  MySource(this.value1, this.value2, this.value3, this.value4, this.value5) {
    //print(value);
  }
  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      onSelectChanged: (changedvalue) {
        print(value1[index].toString());
      },
      index: index,
      cells: [
        DataCell(Text(value1[index].toString())),
        DataCell(Text(value2[index].toString())),
        DataCell(Text(value3[index].toString())),
        DataCell(Text(value4[index].toString())),
        DataCell(m_table_icon(value5[index].toString())),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement isRowCountApproximate
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  // TODO: implement rowCount
  int get rowCount => value1.length;

  @override
  // TODO: implement selectedRowCount
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

and this widget of PaginatedDataTable:

```
   PaginatedDataTable(
                      showCheckboxColumn: false,
                      //header: Text('Header Text'),
                      rowsPerPage: 20,
                      columns: [
                        DataColumn(label: Text('ID')),
                        DataColumn(label: Text('SUB')),
                        DataColumn(
                            label: Text('Created_Date')),
                        DataColumn(
                            label: Text('M_Date')),
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Finish')),
                      ],
```

this to get data from php server:

```
Future get_table_info() async {
    var output = await update_m_table(search_keyword);

    id.clear();
    sub.clear();
    c_date.clear();
    m_date.clear();
    status.clear();

    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        id.add(((output[i].id)));
        sub.add(((output[i].sub)));
        c_date.add(((output[i].created_date)));
        print((output[i].created_date));
        m_date.add(((output[i].date)));
        status.add(((output[i].status)));
      }
    });
  }
```

also I need this, to add search bar when I will lock inside the json data form php.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the issue:

```
output.clear();
```